# Fetching Connected WiFi Network Details In Ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

I am working an ionic project based on IOT. I  need to fetch the details (WiFi name and password ) of **connected WiFi** in my app.I have [used](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/network/) this plugin.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

But this plugin doesn't give much information like name and password of connected WiFi.Is there any plugins or methods for fetching the connected wifi details?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this helps you, but I use the cordova plugins: wifiwizard & cordova-plugin-networkinterface to fetch network information. On iOS it is only possible to get SSID, BSSID, IP, Subnet of connected WiFi & mobile IP, because Apple's Wifi library (Apple80211) is private.

I also use cordova plugins: cordova-plugin-x-toast & cordova-plugin-dialogs for error messages.

The following method readNetwork() stores all network information to $scope.wifi:

```
// read network
function readNetwork() {
    $scope.wifi = {};

    // get current SSID 
    WifiWizard.getCurrentSSID(
        function(ssid) {
            $scope.wifi.ssid = ssid.replace('"','').replace('"','');

            // update scope values in template
            $scope.$apply();
        }, 
        wifiError
    );

    // get current BSSID - ios only
    if(ionic.Platform.isIOS()) {
        WifiWizard.getCurrentBSSID(
            function(bssid) {
                $scope.wifi.bssid = bssid;

                // update scope values in template
                $scope.$apply();
            }, 
            wifiError
        );
    }

    // get list of the available networks as an array of objects - android only
    if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()) {
        WifiWizard.getScanResults(
            function(networks) {
                $scope.wifi.networks = networks;
                //console.log("networks: " + JSON.stringify(networks));

                // find current bssid, if not available
                networks.forEach(function(network) {
                    if(network.SSID == $scope.wifi.ssid) { 
                        $scope.wifi.bssid = network.BSSID;
                        $scope.wifi.level = network.level;
                        $scope.wifi.frequency = network.frequency;
                        $scope.wifi.config = network.capabilities; 
                    }
                });

                // update scope values in template
                $scope.$apply();
            }, 
            wifiError
        );
    }

    // get device's ip adress
    networkinterface.getWiFiIPAddress(
        function(ip, subnet) {  
            $scope.wifi.ip = ip;
            $scope.wifi.subnet= subnet;

            // update scope values in template
            $scope.$apply();
        }, 
        function(error) { 
            $cordovaToast.show("WiFi IP Adresse konnte nicht ermittelt werden: " + error, "long", "center");
            $cordovaDialogs.beep(1); 
        }
    );

    // get device's carrier ip adress
    networkinterface.getCarrierIPAddress(function (ip) { 
        $scope.wifi.vendorIp = ip; 

        // update scope values in template
        $scope.$apply();
    });
}

// read network (wifi) - error
function wifiError(error) {
    $cordovaToast.show("WiFi Fehler: " + error, "long", "center");
    $cordovaDialogs.beep(1);
}
```